# Proving the following sequence is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The sequence $ \{\pi_n\}$ can be defined by  $\pi_1 = 3.1, \pi_2 = 3.14, \pi_3=3.141, ...$ for each $n$, $\pi_n$ shows the first $n$ decimal digits of $\pi$. How can I show that  $\{\pi_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: Could you prove that converges to $\pi$ and then is Cauchy

Answer (score 5):

***Hint:***

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be arbitrary. We can choose $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $\dfrac{1}{10^n} \lt \epsilon$

what happens to $|\pi_m - \pi_{m'}|$ if $m , m' \ge n$??

Answer (score 1):

I think the point of the problem is that $\left\{\pi_n\right\}$ is the decimal approximation of $\pi$, so it is pointless to show that it converges to show Cauchyness. Going back to the problem, you should realize that the first $m$ digits of the difference $\pi_n-\pi_m$ (assuming $n\ge m$) are all $0$. Now, as the indexes $n,m$ goes to infinity (which is the same as saying that $m$ goes to infinity) you get a number $\pi_n-\pi_m$ with compounding zeros as first digits. I hope this will help you write out the $\epsilon-N$ statement to prove Cauchyness.